# RxJava in Android: Auto unsubscribe from subscription when you don't have a life cycle

Tags: android, rx-java, android-syncadapter, subscriptions

I know that when you subscribe to an Observable, you get a Subscription that you have to unsubscribe using the Android's Life cycle.
So in the case of a subscription in a Fragment or an Activity, I use to unsubscribe in the onDestroy().

But my problem is when I do a subscription in places where I don't have any life cycle. For example in a SyncAdapter. In this case (or cases) how could I "auto unsubscribe" to avoid a memory leak?
Is there any good practice that says something like "Never subscribe in XXX place" that I'm breaking with this subscription in the SyncAdapter?

I was thinking in something like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(
   Observable.just()...
   ...
   .doOnTerminate(compositeDisposable::dispose)
   .subscribe(...)
   );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only you can "auto unsubscribe", but also you can choose the thread you want to unsubscribe on. This is a very simple example

```
Observable<Object> source = Observable.using(
() -> {
    System.out.println("Subscribed on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return Arrays.asList(1,2);
},
(ints) -> {
    System.out.println("Producing on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return Observable.from(ints);
},
(ints) -> {
    System.out.println("Unubscribed on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
);

source
.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output should be

```
Subscribed on 1
Producing on 1
1
2
Unubscribed on 11
```

Every `CompositeDisaposable` or `Disposable` or `Subscription` can `unsubscribe`. But make sure you do it when the `stream` is over. Take care about `threading`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: .unsubscribeOn really unsubscribe from the stream or only say where (which thread) to unsubscribe?

Comment: By default, if onError() or onComplete() called, it will unSubscribe your Stream. unSubscribeOn() is useful when you want to specific which thread you want to unSubscribe